# dataTable not working on multiple tabs

Tags: jquery, datatables

My dataTable just works in the latest tab. When i select another one, dataTable just doesn't load.

Need help with loading dataTables on all tables, by the way, even when i switch through tables, they always keep the same ID, so maybe that's the issue.

All entries are being grabbed from my database.

I'm posting the codes right here. Thank you.

**PHP/HTML:**

```
        $rs = $conexion->Consultas($sql);
        if( $rs )
        {
            if ( pg_num_rows($rs) > 0 )
            {
                echo " <table class='table' id='tablaboletas'>";
                echo "<thead>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th style='text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;'>N° Boleta</th>";
                echo "<th style='vertical-align: middle;'>Infractor</th>";
                echo "<th style='vertical-align: middle;'>Funcionario</th>";
                echo "<th style='text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;'>Placa <small>(Vehículo)</small></th>";
                echo "<th style='text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;'>Registro <small>(Fecha)</small></th>";
                echo "<th style='text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;'>Vencimiento <small>(Fecha)</small></th>";
                echo "<th style='text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;'>Estado de Boleta</th>";
                echo "<th style='text-align:center; vertical-align: middle;'><small>Activ. / Desac.</small></th>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</thead>";
                echo "<tbody>";
                while( $obj = pg_fetch_object($rs) ){
                    switch ($i) {
                        case 0: echo "<tr>";
                                break;
                        case 1: echo "<tr class='success'>";
                                break;
                        case 2: echo "<tr class='danger'>";
                                break;
                        case 3: echo "<tr class='info'>";
                                break;
                        case 4: echo "<tr class='warning'>";
                                break;
                        case 5: echo "<tr class='active'>";
                                break;
                     }
                   echo "<td>";
                   echo "<input type='checkbox' value='".$obj->id_boleta."' name='idCheck' > ";
                   echo "<a href='#' onclick=ventana('./FrmBoletaDetalle.php','".$obj->id_boleta."'); return false;><font size='2'>";
                   echo "".completarCerosCodigo($obj->id_boleta);
                   echo "</font><a> ";
                   if ($obj->es_movil == "true" || $obj->es_movil == "t" ){
                    echo "<img src='../../Imagenes/Movil2.png' border='0' width='15' height='20'>";
                   }
                   echo "</td>";
                   echo "<td>".utf8_decode($obj->nombres)." ".utf8_decode($obj->apellidos)."</td>";
                   echo "<td>".utf8_decode($obj->nombre)." ".utf8_decode($obj->apellido)."</td>";
                   echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>".$obj->placa."</td>";
                   echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>".date('d-m-Y',strtotime($obj->fec_registro))."</td>";
                   echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>".date('d-m-Y',strtotime($obj->fec_vencimiento))."</td>";
                   echo "<td style='text-align:center;'>".$obj->descripcion."</td>";      
                   echo "<td style='text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;'>";
                    echo "<input id='checkActivo' name='checkActivo[]'  type='checkbox' value='.$obj->id_boleta.'";
                    if ($obj->status == "t") {
                      echo "checked='checked'";
                    } 
                   echo " onclick=accionStatus('$obj->id_boleta','$obj->status');>";
                   echo "</td>";  
                   echo "</tr>";
                   $i++;
                   if ($i > 5){
                    $i=0;
                   }
                }
                echo "</tbody>";
                echo "</table>";
            } else
                echo "<br><p>No se encontraron coincidencias en este período</p>";
        } else $ok = false;

        return $ok;
    } 
?>
```

**PHP/HTML of tabs:**

```
echo "<div class='tab-content'>";
                while( $obj = pg_fetch_object($rs) ){
                    if ($vesprimeravez){
                        echo "<div id='home' class='tab-pane fade in active'>";
                        mostrarListado($conexion,$obj->periodo,$vidusuario,$vparametro1,$vparametro2,$vparametro3,$vparametro4);
                        echo "</div>";
                        $vesprimeravez = false;
                    } else {
                        echo "<div id='menu".$vi."' class='tab-pane fade'>";
                        mostrarListado($conexion,$obj->periodo,$vidusuario,$vparametro1,$vparametro2,$vparametro3,$vparametro4);
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                    $vi++;
                }
```

**JS:**

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tablaboletas').dataTable();
    });


</script>
```

Comment: When you switch tabs you will probably have to reinitialize the dataTable.

Comment: Yep, that's the solution if you want to use id selector in the script. Thank you for taking your time and answering my question. I've posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! Just needed to change selector item @ jQuery... instead of using 'id', i've used element selector.

JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('table').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: no, this is wrong.  the id selector should work fine regardless of tabs - if this "solved" your problem it's due to some other factor such as a duplicate ID.  while it's true the tabs may mess up the table rendering, it would not have any effect on selecting it by the id attribute